# PrimeFaces dialog: rebuild after empty content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I'm have a datatable much like the crud example:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/crud.xhtml

Problem is: I need to display or hide some detail element in the dialog depending on the row selected. I use `c:if` condition to do that. Problem is, the dialog needs to be rebuild.

So I tried adding `onHide`:

```html
<p:dialog header="Product Details" showEffect="fade" modal="true" widgetVar="manageProductDialog"
onHide="PF('manageProductDialog').content.empty()"
responsive="true">
```

Unfortunately, the dialog opens once but after the second time, it is empty.

What can I do to force the dialog to rebuild itself the second time?

Comment: If the commandButton updates the whole dialog, the show-case works. But I still have my problem : the dialog is not rebuild after changing the row.

Comment: Adding `dynamic=true` to the dialog fixes my problem.